# What is the correct way to create an RTF file in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, file, richtextbox, save

From [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/598a0798-e9c5-4cf4-bfe5-5903b50a54b7) I have seen it suggested that an instance of RichTextBox be created and then it's SaveFile(string path) method be used to get the file onto the hard drive:

```
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();

rtb.SaveFile(@"\MyFileName.rtf");
```

It works, but,..... is this how it should be done, I ask as it seems a little hackish? If not, then what is the correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch779a3b.aspx) says that's exactly how you are supposed to do it.

They also have the following example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.savefile%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
public void SaveMyFile()
{
   // Create a SaveFileDialog to request a path and file name to save to.
   SaveFileDialog saveFile1 = new SaveFileDialog();

   // Initialize the SaveFileDialog to specify the RTF extension for the file.
   saveFile1.DefaultExt = "*.rtf";
   saveFile1.Filter = "RTF Files|*.rtf";

   // Determine if the user selected a file name from the saveFileDialog.
   if(saveFile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK &&
      saveFile1.FileName.Length > 0) 
   {
      // Save the contents of the RichTextBox into the file.
      richTextBox1.SaveFile(saveFile1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
   }
}
```